# EF Core 3.1.9 - FromRawSql using stored procedures stopped working - 'The underlying reader doesn't have as many fields as expected.'

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core

At one point using `FromSqlRaw` to call stored procedures worked for me. I did not change anything in the project but now calling any stored procedure using `FromSqlRaw` returns

> The underlying reader doesn't have as many fields as expected

I removed the model from the project and performed a BUILD. Then added the model back with no luck. I reduced the model and stored procedure to return a single column, no luck.

I tried adding `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational` as a dependency, no luck. All my unit test that use `FromSqlRaw` to call a stored procedure return the same error and at one time they all worked.

I have received Windows updates but nothing I know about that would have affected EF Core. I have run through all internet problem solving I can find. I am starting to think I will need to use ADO as a work around but I do not want a work around when it worked for me at one point. Something changed on my machine but I am not sure what to cause this problem.

Here is my test method in case my code is messed up. It is very straight forward not much to mess up. I tried the "var" out of desperation.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void WorkOrderBOMGridABS()
    {
        List<WorkOrderBOMGridABS> baseList = new List<WorkOrderBOMGridABS>();

        using (WorkOrderDataContext context = new WorkOrderDataContext())
        {
            var param = new SqlParameter[] {
                    new SqlParameter() {
                        ParameterName = "@WorkOrderId",
                        SqlDbType =  System.Data.SqlDbType.Int,
                        Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input,
                        Value = 38385
                    }
            };

            baseList = context.WorkOrderBOMGridABS.FromSqlRaw("[dbo].[WorkOrderBOMGridABS] @WorkOrderId", param).ToList();
            //var results = context.WorkOrderBOMGridABS.FromSqlRaw("[dbo].[WorkOrderBOMGridABS] @WorkOrderId", param).ToList();
            Assert.IsNotNull(baseList);
        }
    }
```

Comment: [The SQL query must return data for all properties of the entity type. The column names in the result set must match the column names that properties are mapped to.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql#limitations)

Comment: Someone changed the stored procedure!

Comment: It is not just one query but all stored procs called via FromRawSql that do not work now and return the same "underlying reader does not have as many fields as expected".  I have verified that all fields in the proc are returned and have the same named property on the model.  I even tried with a single field in both the proc and EF model.  Same response.  I used SQL Profiler to make sure it gets to the SQL Server and it does.

Comment: @BobPenLight I don't like this  [dbo].[WorkOrderBOMGridABS name because it includes dbo. Did you try just  WorkOrderBOMGridABS withoult dbo?

Comment: Thank you Serge I think I added that out of desperation of trying everything.  I have removed it and still same issue.  I had this part of my project completed and have been working on a system integration piece for a month and not run through this code.  It was not until I was ready to create a package for deployment and was running my unit tests that they failed.  Only the methods that call stored procs from FromSqlRaw failed.  I tried updating to latest 3.1.17 for EntityFrameworkCore libraries without success still same failure on just FromRawSql stored proc calls.

Answer (score 1):

I was using an old table to get the Unit Of Measure value that had an integer ID value.  I switched it to use a new table with a VARCHAR ID value.  Making this change to the stored proc and model code allowed the FromRawSql to work.  Not sure why because while the integer ID value was getting an integer, either 0 or number other than 0, it was a valid value for the model.  Any error message I received did not mention this UnitId field.  It was a pain but I am glad it is resolved.  At least until the next error I run into that much is guaranteed.